# TextClock font not being applied from style

Tags: android, xml

I have two `TextClocks` within a `Toolbar`:

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/Toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0">


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/time_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="24px">

        <TextClock
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:format12Hour="EEEE, d MMM  yyyy"
                android:format24Hour="EEEE, d MMM  yyyy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Toolbar"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextClock
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Toolbar"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have given them both the style "Toolbar" defined in styles.xml like this:

```
<style name="Toolbar" >

    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/greycliff_cf_bold</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/toolbars</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/navBarText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20px</item>

</style>
```

However, while the TextClocks are taking the style's color, they are not taking the specified font. Other views in the project also have that font and appear as they should. What is happening?

Comment: In the TextClock element try the following: put android:fontFamily="@font/greycliff_cf_bold" after android:textAppearance="@style/Toolbar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to set it programmatically:

```
private lateinit var timeClock:TextClock

timeClock=findViewById(R.id.time_text_clock)

val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(Context,R.font.font_name)

timeClock.typeface = typeface
```